# Multiple commands in a pcmanfm-qt custom action?

Tags: linux, pipe, pandoc, file-manager, pcmanfm

**SOLUTION AND THE COMPLETE EXEC LINE**

```
Exec=sh -c 'sed -i "1s:.*:<body background=%f>:" /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd && pandoc -f markdown /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd --css /home/burak/Public/CSS/pandoc2.css -s -S -w html -o /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.html && phantomjs /home/burak/bin/shortcuts.js file:///home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.html /home/burak/Not/shortcuts.jpg 1920px*1080px && feh --bg-fill /home/burak/Not/shortcuts.jpg'
```

---

This is likely relevant to other file managers using the same ([DES-EMA](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/?q=node/377)) scheme.

I've got four commands all working individually, yet I stuck just at adding the second command to the Exec line of the custom action. If I overcome this, the other two remaining commands can be added accordingly (or by piping) I suppose.

Here are my commands and infos about what they're meant to do (the %f, obviously, to be expanded to the file clicked on in the file manager):

```
sed -i "1s:.*:<body background=%f>:" /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd
```

The above command replaces the first line of that markdown file which changes the background image of html file to be produced by pandoc with the following second command:

```
pandoc -f markdown /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd --css /home/burak/Public/CSS/pandoc2.css -s -S -w html -o /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.html
```

The below third command converts that Shortcuts.html to shortcuts.jpg

```
phantomjs shortcuts.js file:///home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.html shortcuts.jpg 1920px*1080px
```

And finally the below fourth command sets the above shortcuts.jpg image as the desktop wallpaper (with all the shortcuts, bash aliases and some other commands embedded into the desktop).

```
feh --bg-fill %f
```

So at the end I would easly change wallpaper and embed my keyboard shortcuts and aliases etc. into every new wallpaper like so:

[wallpaper with shortcuts embeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0NcJ.jpg)

Now, as said previously, I've stuck at the begining, that is, can't add the second command to the first. I've tried this without success:

```
Exec=sed -i "1s:.*:<body background=%f>:" /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd && pandoc -f markdown /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd --css /home/burak/Public/CSS/pandoc2.css -s -S -w html -o /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.html
```

And neither this has worked:

```
Exec=sh -c "sed -i "1s:.*:<body background=%f>:" /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd && pandoc -f markdown /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd --css /home/burak/Public/CSS/pandoc2.css -s -S -w html -o /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.html"
```

And piping (|) those two commands works in terminal, but not in custom action desktop file.

What should I do (on Arch Linux with Fluxbox if that matters)?

Answer (score 0):

Damn!.. Thought I've tried this before, but seemingly not in this way. Well, piping in this manner works:

```
Exec:sh -c 'sed "1s:.*:<body background=%f>:" < /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.mkd | pandoc --css /home/burak/Public/CSS/pandoc2.css -s -S -w html -o /home/burak/Not/Shortcuts.html'
```